# Replacing elements of a nested list by some value

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I have a list of list

```
A= {{0.620161, 0.320312, 0.94842, 1.11844, 1.12045, 1.12539, 1.13177, 
  1.13142, 1.15048, 1.23244, 0.721388, 0.708943, 0.750067, 0.744916, 
  0.720972, 0.674833, 1.29773, 1.29514}, {0.620161, 0.320312, 0.94842,
   1.11844, 1.12045, 1.12539, 1.13177, 1.13142, 1.15048, 0.721388, 
  0.750067, 0.744916, 0.720972, 0.674833, 1.29383, 
  1.29514}, {0.620161, 0.320312, 0.94842, 1.11844, 1.12045, 1.12539, 
  1.13177, 1.13142, 1.15048, 0.721388, 0.750067, 0.744916, 0.720972, 
  0.674833, 1.29383, 1.29514}, {0.620161, 0.320312, 0.94842, 1.11844, 
  1.12539, 1.13177, 1.13142, 1.15048, 0.721388, 0.750067, 0.744916, 
  0.720972, 0.674833, 1.29383, 1.29514}, .... }}.
```

The number of lists inside is not known. I want to replace all the elements of the first list by 20, all the elements of the second list by 20.1 and so on for all the lists.

I tried `ReplaceList` but with no success, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You can start with `list[[1,;;]]=20`. It should be easy to generalize this in the way you need it.

Comment: Yes, I know how to do list by list, but I don't know how to generalize or do it automatically for all the lists. Even the resources on Wolfram don't say most of the stuff that are discussed here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ClearAll[miF, rPF, tBF];
miF = MapIndexed[20 + .1 (#2[[1]] - 1) &, #, {2}] &;
```

or

```
rPF = ReplacePart[#, {i_, _} :> (19.9 + 0.1 i)] &;
```

or

```
tbF = Block[{j = 0}, Table[ 0 i + 20 + 0.1 j++, {i, #}]] &;
```

Example:

```
A = {{0.620161, 0.320312, 0.94842, 1.11844, 1.12045, 1.12539, 1.13177,
     1.13142, 1.15048, 1.23244, 0.721388, 0.708943, 0.750067, 
    0.744916, 0.720972, 0.674833, 1.29773, 1.29514}, {0.620161, 
    0.320312, 0.94842, 1.11844, 1.12045, 1.12539, 1.13177, 1.13142, 
    1.15048, 0.721388, 0.750067, 0.744916, 0.720972, 0.674833, 
    1.29383, 1.29514}, {0.620161, 0.320312, 0.94842, 1.11844, 1.12045,
     1.12539, 1.13177, 1.13142, 1.15048, 0.721388, 0.750067, 0.744916,
     0.720972, 0.674833, 1.29383, 1.29514}, {0.620161, 0.320312, 
    0.94842, 1.11844, 1.12539, 1.13177, 1.13142, 1.15048, 0.721388, 
    0.750067, 0.744916, 0.720972, 0.674833, 1.29383, 1.29514}};

miF@A
(* {{20., 20., 20., 20., 20., 20., 20., 20., 20., 20., 20., 20., 20., 20., 20., 20., 20., 20.},
    {20.1, 20.1, 20.1, 20.1, 20.1, 20.1, 20.1,  20.1, 20.1, 20.1, 20.1, 20.1,
     20.1, 20.1, 20.1, 20.1}, 
    {20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2,
     20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2}, 
    {20.3, 20.3, 20.3, 20.3, 20.3, 20.3, 20.3, 20.3, 20.3, 20.3, 20.3, 20.3,
     20.3, 20.3, 20.3}} *)

miF @ A == rPF @ A == tbF @ A
(* True  *)
```

Comment: To a person who has never programmed before, this seems like magic. Thank you.

Comment: @Nilanjan, my pleasure. Welcome to Mathematica.SE.

Comment: This is a rather inefficient method as you apply the function to *every* element rather than using a vector operation.

Answer (score 11):

Another interesting approach:

```
i = 0;
Map[0 # + (20 + 0.1 i++) &, A]
```

> ```
> {{20., 20., 20., 20., 20., 20., 20., 20., 20., 20., 20., 20., 20., 
>   20., 20., 20., 20., 20.}, {20.1, 20.1, 20.1, 20.1, 20.1, 20.1, 20.1,
>    20.1, 20.1, 20.1, 20.1, 20.1, 20.1, 20.1, 20.1, 20.1}, {20.2, 20.2,
>    20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 
>   20.2, 20.2, 20.2}, {20.3, 20.3, 20.3, 20.3, 20.3, 20.3, 20.3, 20.3, 
>   20.3, 20.3, 20.3, 20.3, 20.3, 20.3, 20.3}}
> ```

Comment: The easiest approach, indeed

Answer (score 5):

Using:

```
A = {{0.620161, 0.320312, 0.94842, 1.11844, 1.12045, 1.12539, 1.13177,
     1.13142, 1.15048, 1.23244, 0.721388, 0.708943, 0.750067, 
    0.744916, 0.720972, 0.674833, 1.29773, 1.29514}, {0.620161, 
    0.320312, 0.94842, 1.11844, 1.12045, 1.12539, 1.13177, 1.13142, 
    1.15048, 0.721388, 0.750067, 0.744916, 0.720972, 0.674833, 
    1.29383, 1.29514}, {0.620161, 0.320312, 0.94842, 1.11844, 1.12045,
     1.12539, 1.13177, 1.13142, 1.15048, 0.721388, 0.750067, 0.744916,
     0.720972, 0.674833, 1.29383, 1.29514}, {0.620161, 0.320312, 
    0.94842, 1.11844, 1.12539, 1.13177, 1.13142, 1.15048, 0.721388, 
    0.750067, 0.744916, 0.720972, 0.674833, 1.29383, 1.29514}};
```

A function to replace list:

```
rep[a_, v_] := MapThread[Table[#2, {Length@#1}] &, {a, v}]
```

so

```
rep[A, 19.9 + Range[Length[A]]/10]
```

yields:

```
{{20., 20., 20., 20., 20., 20., 20., 20., 20., 20., 20., 20., 20., 
  20., 20., 20., 20., 20.}, {20.1, 20.1, 20.1, 20.1, 20.1, 20.1, 20.1,
   20.1, 20.1, 20.1, 20.1, 20.1, 20.1, 20.1, 20.1, 20.1}, {20.2, 20.2,
   20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 20.2, 
  20.2, 20.2, 20.2}, {20.3, 20.3, 20.3, 20.3, 20.3, 20.3, 20.3, 20.3, 
  20.3, 20.3, 20.3, 20.3, 20.3, 20.3, 20.3}}
```

Comment: `ConstantArray` would be better than `Table` here as the latter assumes a changing value. +1 nevertheless.

Answer (score 5):

Borrowing from existing answers:

```
19.9 + Range@Length@A/10 + 0 A
```

Comment: Why is it oftentimes so difficult to see the simple things?

Answer (score 4):

```
Table[A[[i, All]] = Table[20. + n/10, {n, 0, Length[A] - 1}][[i]], {i, 1, Length[A]}];

A // TableForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Two more:

```
19.9 + #1/10 + 0 #2 & @@@ Transpose@{Range@Length@A, A}
```

or

```
Transpose@{Range@Length@A, A} /. {x_, y_} :> 0 y + 19.9 + x/10
```